# Switch between threads

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, wait, executorservice, notify

How can I switch between threads created from thread pool? I have many threads created but I only want 1 thread to print something and others to be in wait state. Now after printing, I want this thread to go in wait state and some other thread to acquire this lock and print just like the previous thread and then go into wait state. This simulation keeps on occuring again and again until some condition satisfies. There is randomization of threads acquiring the lock and it doesn't need to be in order. If possible later you can exlain how can I achieve that in order maybe using queue.

I am new to threads, so something that I was trying to achieve is below. I know its wrong but I wanted you to give a solution and little explanation in terms of what I want to achieve.

```
public class Processor implements Runnable{
    private int id;
    public Processor(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count=0;
        System.out.println("Starting process id: " + id);
        while(count<100) {
            System.out.println("Pausing process id: "+id);
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Resuming process id: "+id);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Completed process id: " + id);
    }
}



public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of processes you want to create: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
        for(int i=1;i<=n; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Processor(i));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't switch between threads, they run independently, so that approach is not possible. However, there are many synchronization primitives, like e.g. mutex, you can use those to coordinate the threads with each other. However, if you want them to operate in a particular order, using threading isn't the right tool, because their advantage is that they operate independently.

Comment: you can switch oneway by putting thread in sleep mode , that is not recomended ..

Comment: I don't want to use sleep, @UlrichEckhardt can you explain using code if possible.

Comment: You just need to read the tutorial further from which you are learning about threads and you should look in the documentation what things your programming language offers. It's way too much to explain in an answer here.

Comment: You could use a mutex or semaphore to only allow one thread at a time to run, but the order of threads would be OS dependent, and it would be possible that only one thread would ever run. Windows tends to wake up threads in the order they issue WaitFor... calls, but this doesn't happen with other operating systems. Using one mutex or semaphore per thread would allow the order to be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically control the order in which threads are instantiated. The priority of threads and their execution is determined by the particular Operating System's thread scheduling algorithm implementation.